# Node.js intellisense in WebStorm and/or VS Code

Tags: node.js, intellisense, webstorm, visual-studio-code

Is it me or there's no node.js intellisense in Visual Studio Code and Webstorm 10 ?
For example when I have `var http = require('http')` then `http.` does not include `createServer` as a suggestion.

How can I make intellisense work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In webstorm to enable intellisense for node.js core modules you need to configure node sources which can be done under Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM -> Click on configure. Webstorm will download the sources for the node version installed on your system and attach it to the open project. Enjoy Webstorm's awesome intellisense. :)

Answer (score 2):

And for VisualStudio Code:

First, install Typings

```
npm install -g typings
```

Then, using the Typings command line, pull down the Node.js and Express type definition files

```
typings install dt~node --global
typings install dt~express dt~serve-static dt~express-serve-static-core --global
```

You may find more details from: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs